# how to solve cannot resolve symbol when u dont know which class does it belong to

Tags: android

```
DrawableRequestBuilder drawableRequestBuilder = Glide.with(This
            .load(foodMenu.getImage()).into(viewHolder.imageView).fitCenter().animate(android.R.anim.fade_in);

    if (mMediaFragmentListener.getLocalVideoUri() != null) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        Context context = getContext();
        retriever.setDataSource(context, mMediaFragmentListener.getLocalVideoUri());
        Bitmap frame = retriever.getFrameAtTime();
        drawableRequestBuilder.placeholder(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), frame));
    }

    drawableRequestBuilder.into(mThumbnailView);
```

I used the above code for loading image like in instagram until it fully downloads from the server. But i dont why do i get error on mMediaFragmentListener and mThumbnailView as cannot resolve symbol. ANd i dont know why.  I used it from the link [here](http://code.hootsuite.com/load-images-in-android-using-glide/).

Comment: where are mMediaFragmentListener and mThumbnailView defined?

Comment: You can see the link i provided for reference. BUt I have no idea where it is or should be defined @WillEvers

Comment: you should not expect others to visit a random site to help you, there are hundred of other questions which are better detailed and therefore you are only making people skip your question because of being incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to my comment and the error you got. you did not define  mMediaFragmentListener and mThumbnailView, therefore it can't resolve them.

Comment: how do i define them?